# Query a collection using a variable defined within the collections documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want the user to find nearby restaurants that are within the restaurants delivery range. At the moment I can define the delivery range using a number, (eg as shown below 1000 (m)).

The problem is, I want my restaurants to define their own delivery range. Therefore, I have saved within the restaurants JSON documents a variable called 'range'. I want to use that variable (range) from within the document being queried.

I hope that makes sense!

```
router.get('/getRestaurants', function(req, res, next) {
  var coordinates = [];
  geocoder.geocode(req.query.postcode)
    .then(function(location) {
      console.log(location);
      coordinates = [location[0].longitude, location[0].latitude];
      console.log(coordinates)
      Restaurant.find({
        location_2dsphere: {
          $near: {
            $maxDistance: 1000, // i want to swap 1000 with 'range' that is defined in the JSON document being queried
            $geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: coordinates
            }
          }
        }
      })
       .then(restaurantData => {
         res.status(200).json(restaurantData)
       })
       .catch(error => {
         res.status(400).json({ message: "error", error: err })
       });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregation with `$geoNear` as first stage to calculate the distance, then `$cmp` to calculate if distance or range is bigger and then `$match` to filter out the results.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/